# Question from proof of Rauch Comparison Theorem (ref. do Carmo p 215)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am confused about a statement from do Caromo's proof of the Rauch Comparison Theorem. This is on page 215 of his textbook.

He says the following:

Since $\langle J, \gamma' \rangle \gamma'=\langle J'(0),\gamma'(0)\rangle t\gamma' + \langle J(0),\gamma'(0)\rangle \gamma'$

the tangential components of $J$ and $\tilde{J}$ have, by hypothesis, the same length.

Therefore we can suppose that $\langle J, \gamma'\rangle = 0 = \langle \tilde{J},\tilde{\gamma}' \rangle$.

> I don't understand why this simplification. In particular, why does the first statement imply they have the same length and why can we (and why are we) assuming the second statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A =(J',\gamma ')(0),\ B=(J,\gamma')(0)$,

Let $$J= f\gamma '+W$$
where $f=A t + B,\ \gamma'\perp W$.

(1) Here $f\gamma'$ is Jacobi so that so is $W$. Hence now we will check that $W,\ \widetilde{W}$ **satisfies the assumptions**.

(2) $J(0)=B \gamma' + W(0)$

(3) $(J',\gamma ')(0)= (A \gamma ' +W' ,\gamma') =A+ (W',\gamma')(0)$

(4) $|J'(0)|^2 =| A\gamma' +W'|^2 = A^2+|W'|^2$ since

$$(\gamma',W')(0)=(\gamma',J'-A\gamma')=0$$